# IOS Firebase Invitation crashing while loading contacts Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-authentication, firebase-invites

I implemented Firebase invite method and it works great for the first time. But after that, while I trying to invite it crashed. I can't trace where it from but asked in log about:

> malloc_error_break

While I add this symbolic breakpoint in my project it hangs my app and give these errors: (see in pics)

[image: shows thread error]

and

[image: debug error]

which I can't trace why happened this? If any anyone can't give a solution at least help me trace the problem out.

Comment: set an exception breakpoint. You may get a break when the error happens instead of in main, where the exception gets passed up.

Comment: already tried. but still, give the same error.